# error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `0,2', expecting `.' or `['

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I imported an old project to Unity 5.6.of3 and I got this error
error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `0,2', expecting`.' or `['
when I click on it, it takes me to this line:

```
 float newVisibleAreaLength = tk2dUIControlsHelperEditor.DrawLengthHandles("Visible Area Length", scrollableArea.VisibleAreaLength,scrollableArea.contentContainer.transform.position, isYAxis? -up:right, Color.red,isYAxis?.2f:-.2f, 0, .05f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by updating 2d Toolkit